# When sending a response error from AuthenticationEntryPoint, 'network error' occurs on the client screen axios

Tags: axios, response

Below is the written java code

```
@Slf4j
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String expired = (String) httpServletRequest.getAttribute("expired");
        if (expired!=null){
            //httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,ErrorCode.C401.getDetailCode());
            setErrorResponse(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,httpServletResponse);

        }else{
            httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Invalid Login details");
        }
    }

    public void setErrorResponse(HttpStatus status, HttpServletResponse response){
        response.setStatus(status.value());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.C401.getDetailCode(),ErrorCode.C401.getMessage() );
        try{
            String json = errorResponse.convertToJson();
            System.out.println(json);
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

token is expired then above code start.

works very well in postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cGC7.png)

but client axios occur 'network error'

Why does this happen?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOYbR.png)

i try to send response error in filter but this fail